# Proof by induction. For $7$ divides $2^{3n} − 1$ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

So, I want to check if this proof works as the answer does it slightly differently.

Proof:
Let $p(n)$ denote the statement $2^{3n} - 1$ divides 7

Base case:
$n=1 : 2^{3(1)} -1 = 8-1 = 7$, which divdes $7$. So p(1) is true

let $n \geq 2$ and let $p(n)$ hold for $2^{3n} -1 = 7k$ for some integer $k$

$p(n+1) = 2^{3(n+1)} -1                                                                                      
\\p(n+1) = 2^{3n+3} -1                                                                                    
\\p(n+1) = 2^3(7k+1)-1                                                                              
\\p(n+1) = 56k+8-1                                                                                    
\\p(n+1)= 56k+7                                                                                                                                               
\\p(n+1)= 7(8k+1)$

so $p(n+1)$ is true

so by induction $p(n)$ is true for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

---

Comment: Please use Mathjax to write mathematics properly in this site. It's very hard to understand as you wrote it.

Comment: @peterwhy The expression is $\;2^{3n}-1\;$ , so for $\;n=2\;$ we'd get$\;2^6-1=63=7\cdot9\;$

Comment: The second formula for $\;p(n+1)\;$ is wrong after the editing. It should be $\;p(n+1)=2^{3n}\cdot2^3-1\;$

Comment: If your base case is $n=1$ you can't Let $n\ge 2$ in your inductions step.   You can't every assume $n$ is greater than a demonstrated case.  (Else you get the All horses are the same color problem).

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry, I did it on my phone. I'll make sure to use that site next time

Comment: Proof is good. But as your base case is $n=1$ assume $n\ge 1$ in your induction step.  Also word $p(n)$ as either "$2^{3n}-1$ is divisible by $7$" or "$2^{3n}-1=7k_n$ for some integer $k_n$".  As you have stated it here, it sounds like it is always the *same* $k$ for every $n$ which, of course, it is not.

Comment: @peterwhy yeah, I noticed that and changed it.

Comment: You let $p(n)$ denote the statement $2^{3n}-1$ divides $7$. Each $p(n)$ is not a number but a true-or-false statement, and you can't say "$p(n+1) = 2^{3(n+1)}-1$" etc.

Comment: Also just because I like elementary proofs to be truly elementary I would add just two lines of clarifier  $.p(n+1) = 2^{3(n+1)} -1               
\\p(n+1) = 2^{3n+3} -1
\\p(n+1) =\color{blue}{2^3\cdot 2^{3n} -1}
\\p(n+1)=\color{blue}{2^3((2^{3n} - 1)+1)-1}
\\p(n+1) = 56k+8-1
\\p(n+1)= 56k+7                               
\\p(n+1)= 7(5k+1)
\\$.   Oh, I also wouldn't lead with the "$p(n+1)=....$.  $p(n+1)$ are statements and those are all values.

Comment: @peterwhy ,So would I just remove that and just start with stuff on the right ?

Comment: I would prefer to just start with $2^{3(n+1)}-1 = \ldots$ in the induction steps.

Comment: @peterwhy Thank You for that

Answer (score 1):

Here a trick for you to save (full) induction and instead to rely on what I call "hidden induction", using the basic formula $\;a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})\;$:

$$2^{3n}-1=8^n-1^n=(8-1)(8^{n-1}+8{n-2}+\ldots+8+1)$$

...and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

So we can assume the result is true for $n$, that is $2^{3n} - 1 = 7k$ for some $k$, then $2^{3(n+1)} - 1 = 8 \times 2^{3n} - 8 + 7 = 56k + 7 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$

Answer (score 0):

$P(n+1)$=$\;2^{3(n+1)}-1\;$ = $2^{3n+3}-1$
= $2^{3n}\times 2^3-1$
= $8(2^{3n})-1$
= $8(2^{3n}-1)+7$
= $8(7k)+7$
= $7(8k+1)$
= $7k'$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).